# Using Thread.CurrentPrincipal with async and await?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

Consider the following code that sets a ClaimsPrincipal on a single, main thread of execution and then runs a task and tries to access the ClaimsPrincipal:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Setting the CurrentPrincipal on the main thread
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim("name", "bob"), new Claim("role", "admin") }, "CUSTOM", "name", "role"));
        Console.WriteLine("Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine("Thread.CurrentPrincipal?.Identity?.Name " + (Thread.CurrentPrincipal?.Identity?.Name ?? "null"));

            AsyncHelper.RunSync(
            async () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tInside Async Method - Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Console.WriteLine("\tInside Async Method - Thread.CurrentPrincipal?.Identity?.Name " + (Thread.CurrentPrincipal?.Identity?.Name ?? "null"));

                //Simulate long(er) running work
                await Task.Delay(2000);

                Console.WriteLine("\tInside Async Method - Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Console.WriteLine("\tInside Async Method - Thread.CurrentPrincipal?.Identity?.Name " + (Thread.CurrentPrincipal?.Identity?.Name ?? "null"));
            });

        Console.WriteLine("Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine("Thread.CurrentPrincipal?.Identity?.Name " + (Thread.CurrentPrincipal?.Identity?.Name ?? "null"));
    }
}
```

and

```
internal static class AsyncHelper
{
    private static readonly TaskFactory MyTaskFactory = new
        TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.None,
            TaskContinuationOptions.None,
            TaskScheduler.Default);

    public static void RunSync(Func<Task> func)
    {
        AsyncHelper.MyTaskFactory
                .StartNew<Task>(func)
                .Unwrap()
                .GetAwaiter()
                .GetResult();
    }
}
```

The output of the program is

```
Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId 2
Thread.CurrentPrincipal?.Identity?.Name bob
        Inside Async Method - Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId 3
        Inside Async Method - Thread.CurrentPrincipal?.Identity?.Name null
        Inside Async Method - Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId 3
        Inside Async Method - Thread.CurrentPrincipal?.Identity?.Name null
Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId 2
Thread.CurrentPrincipal?.Identity?.Name bob
Press any key to exit
```

What I ***thought*** I would see is this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId 2
Thread.CurrentPrincipal?.Identity?.Name bob
        Inside Async Method - Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId 3
        Inside Async Method - Thread.CurrentPrincipal?.Identity?.Name bob <--- Notice here
        Inside Async Method - Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId 3
        Inside Async Method - Thread.CurrentPrincipal?.Identity?.Name bob <--- Notice here
Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId 2
Thread.CurrentPrincipal?.Identity?.Name bob
Press any key to exit
```

What happened to the `ClaimsPrincipal` that was set on the main thread (in the case of this specific output ManagedThreadId 2)? Why did the ClaimsPrincipal not get copied to the other thread when the ExecutionContext was copied?

***Update***: The .Net target framework is .NET Core 2.0.

***Update 2***: This issue seems to be specific to .NET Core. Using the same code but instead targeting the .NET 4.6.1 framework I get the output I expect.

Comment: On which .NET version do you run this?

Comment: The target framework is .NET Core 2.0. I think I may try it on another version and see what happens.

Comment: I guess on full .net (like 4.6) it should work as you expect

Comment: I do get the output I expect. Can you explain why? If you put an explanation in an answer I will accept it.

Comment: To some extent, this just provides another demonstration that trying to marry the `Thread`-related and `Task`-related worlds together rarely works seamlessly. They're different abstractions and you shouldn't really be mixing them together.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I agree completely. I hate Thread.CurrentPrincipal. I'd much rather go for a dependency injection based solution instead of a public static mutable property that was created before people cared about unit testing (Thread.CurrentPrincipal). However in this particular case I am bound to a legacy implementation.

Comment: I can only say it's implemented that way in .net core. In full .net principal is implemented in a way to flow through async calls. In .net core - it's just a property which returns value of regular field, so it doesn't flow. So, by design.

Comment: Can you be more clear on what parts you *do* have control over versus which ones you cannot, for your real problem then? Because clearly here we could just have the lambda capture a `principal` variable which is initialized instead of setting `CurrentPrincipal`.

Answer (score 1):

You just can't rely on thread properties, since such details as threads assignment to the task depends on concrete ThreadScheduler ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(v=vs.110).aspx ) . There are many different ThreadScheduler implementations.

There is an option to implement your own custom TaskScheduler where you will set Thread.CurrentPrincipal to your values, but better just do not rely on all threading properties at all staying on "task level".